# Optimize trigger to write data on data warehouse

Tags: postgresql

We are using using trigger to store the data on warehouse. Whenever some process is executed a trigger fires and store some information on the data warehouse. When number of transactions increase it affects the processing time.

What would be the best way to do this activity ?

I was thinking about `Foreign Data Wrapper` or `AWS Read replica`. Is there any other way to do such activity would be appreciated as well. Or I might not have to use trigger at all ?

Comment: Do you actually need data to be written across instantly? You might find an hourly refresh is fine. In this case you batch the data out in an hourly fashion.

Answer (score 1):

Here are quick tips

1. Reduce latency between database server
2. Target database table should have less index, To Improve DML Performance
3. Logical replication may solve syncing data to warehouse

Option 3 is an architectural change, though you don't need to write triggers on each table to sync data